# Замена строки в txt файле на произвольную строку из другого txt файла по расписанию

Tags: bat

Для замены ключей доступа к сервису геокодирования необходимо менять раз в 4-5 дней этот самый ключ доступа. 
Есть 2 файла. Оба в корне. В одном список ключей. Во второй система смотрит за текущим актуальным ключем доступа и в нем по сути вообще всего одна строка. Каким образом можно прописать батник (и задать его в задачи по расписанию видимо?) чтобы при его запуске из первого брался ключ (каждый ключ одной строкой) и заменялся в другом файле?

Comment: Какая ОС? Можно ли использовать скриптовый язык с более богатыми возможностями?

Comment: Приведите пример содержимого обеих файлов. Сформулируйте чёткие критерии поиска строк (как заменяемой, так и заменяющей).